# Spring Data JPA using EclipseLink as JPA provider: possible bug in EclipseLink?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA and EclipseLink 2.5.2 as my JPA provider. The database I use is PostgreSQL. I have a table that has an auto increment serial ID as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE segment
(
  caseid character varying(32),
  segmentid serial NOT NULL,
  segstarttime timestamp without time zone,
  segendtime timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT segment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (segmentid)
);
```

In the Java data class `Segment`, I defined it as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="segment")
public class Segment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="segment_segmentid_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="segment_segmentid_seq", sequenceName="segment_segmentid_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private Integer segmentID;
    private String caseID;
    private Timestamp segStartTime;
    private Timestamp segEndTime;
}
```

Then I have the following Spring Data JPA code to test insert into function to the database:

```
    Segment seg2 = new Segment();
    seg2.setCaseID("000014");
    seg2.setSegStartTime(Timestamp.valueOf("2014-08-01 10:36:39"));
    seg2.setSegEndTime(Timestamp.valueOf("2014-08-02 14:22:08"));
    seg2 = repository.save(seg2);

    Segment seg3 = repository.findOne(seg2.getSegmentID());
```

When I run the above test code, something strange happens. The above code should only insert one record to the table and the serial ID `segmentid` should only increment by 1 after calling the above code. However, I found that the auto increment segmentid incremented by 2 after this `save()` is called. But if I directly type the SQL query in PostgreSQL command line:

```
INSERT INTO segment (caseid, segstarttime, segendtime) VALUES ('000014', '2014-08-01 10:36:39', '2014-08-02 14:22:08');
```

It works properly and the auto increment serial ID `segmentid` only incremented by 1 after insertion. I'm really puzzled by this behavior. Then I changed my JPA provider from EclipseLink 2.5.2 to Hibernate 4.3.6 and tried running the above Java code again. It works normally and the `segmentid` also gets incremented by 1 after calling `save()` method of `CrudRepository` class.

So is this a possible bug of EclipseLink JPA? Or is it due to some bugs in Spring Data JPA integration with EclipseLink?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence generator should normally mean that EclipseLink puts the value for that column into the INSERT statement. Except that if you have AUTOINCREMENT column (SERIAL) then you should set the generator to be `IDENTITY` to match the column you have there. `SEQUENCE` means it will get its value from a Sequence (surprise surprise), not auto-increment.

Comment: Yes, this is a big surprise. I changed the `GenerationType` from `SEQUENCE` to `IDENTITY` then it works as normal in EclipseLink JPA. But even if I use `SEQUENCE` in Hibernate JPA, it still works and increments by 1 every time. So Hibernate and EclipseLink have different behavior on `SERIAL` type for PostgreSQL. Also since PostgreSQL keeps auto increment id in a SEQUENCE table, why does it not work if I put it as `SEQUENCE`? I assume that EclipseLink will read the auto increment id from PostgreSQL SEQUENCE table which generates the `AUTO INCREMENT` id.

Comment: Your metadata is what DEFINEs what the datastore should be. If you asked EclipseLink to generate the schema (for consistency) perhaps it would not put SERIAL when you had SEQUENCE?